# Fake filesystem for Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, filesystems, virtual

I'm in need of some code which fakes the actual file system to a fake one. So, when I start it it converts `/home/user/Documents/fake_fs` to `/`, so every `Dir` or `File` call goes to that directory. An example:

I want to make a file on `/some_file`, so I use:

```
File.open('/some_file', 'w') do |f|
  f.puts 'something on this file'
end
```

And it would write it on `/home/user/Documents/fake_fs/some_file` instead of `/some_file`. Is there any way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: I **think** [chroot](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-chroot) would achieve this.

Comment: Well, I though of it initially but after reading the docs, I think it's not suitable for it. It would be some code that when run, "redirects" all the filesystem calls to the faked path

Comment: I think maybe `fakefs` gem is what you're looking for: https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs

Comment: I also took a look at `fakefs`, but it's designed just for tests, not for actual code (I think)

Comment: chroot would be the more secure options, otherwise you can have a look at fuse: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/619

Answer (score 3):

You've got two options:

### Option 1 - Use a Gem to Fake it out

[FakeFS](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs.git) will do exactly what you want, with the caveat that some file system operations won't work.  FakeFS rewrites various file-manipulating calls in Ruby standard lib, so something might be missed, or something might not work right.

### Option 2 - Rework your code to make it more testable

You are essentially hardcoding `/` as the root of where your app starts looking for files.  If you make this configurable, your code can manipulate this for tests.

For example:

```
$root = ENV['ROOT_DIR'] || '/'
File.open(File.join($root,'some_file'),'w') do |file|
  # whatever
end
```

Your tests can then set `ROOT_DIR` to be a location you set up just like you want.

`chroot` might also help in doing this, e.g.

```
Dir.chroot(ENV['ROOT_DIR'] || '/')

File.open('/some_file','w') do |file|
  # whatever
end
```

See `man chroot` for more on that.

Personally, I'd go with option 2.